# Collection in Java

Tags: java

Quick Question...
Can collections in Java hold more than one type? Or do they all have to be the same type?

thanks

Comment: The problem of this kind of question is: 1) they have been asked several times. 2) they attract a lot of low quality answers, because it is a topic where even a novice knows *something* about. As a result (on top of it) most answers here contain mistakes, just because they are posted by novice developers. In my opinion this question should be closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining a type for a Java Collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281996/defining-a-type-for-a-java-collection)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Simple answer

Yes.

### More detailed answer

You can either use generic collection, without `<T>` value, for example:

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
a.add(2);
a.add("String");
```

Using collections without `<T>` is a bad habit and most IDEs / compilers give a warning here. You can circumvent it by using a collection of `Object`, i.e.:

```
ArrayList<Object> a = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Or you can find some common interface or supertype that these element must have in, for example `ArrayList<Number>` - and you can store various objects that have common `Number` superclass, i.e. BigDecimal, BigInteger, Byte, Double, Float, Integer, Long, Short:

```
ArrayList<Number> a = new ArrayList<Number>();
a.add(2); // integer
a.add(42L); // long
a.add(123.45d); // double
System.out.println(a.toString()); // => [2, 42, 123.45]
```

Note that it essentially means that `a` elements are of `Number` class — i.e. you can't ask to execute subclass-specific methods (for example, [Double#isInfinite()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isInfinite()), which doesn't exist in `Number` superclass), although you can typecast in run-time if you somehow know it's safe to typecast:

```
a.get(2).isInfinite()          // compile-time error
((Double) a.get(2)).isInfinite() // => false
((Double) a.get(1)).isInfinite() // run-time error (ClassCastException)
```

Run-time typecasting is also generally frowned upon, as it effectively circumvents proper compile-time type safety.

Also note that it's impossible to assign (or use) `ArrayList<Number>` in place of `ArrayList<Integer>` and vice-versa, i.e. this will fail to compile:

```
public void printNumbers(ArrayList<Number> list) {
    list.forEach(System.out::println);
}
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
printNumbers(a); // "incompatible types"
```

as well as this:

```
public void printIntegers(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    list.forEach(System.out::println);
}
ArrayList<Number> a = new ArrayList<Number>();
printIntegers(a); // "incompatible types"
```

To declare a variable to be able to accept both `ArrayList<Number>` or any of its subclasses, one can use `ArrayList<? extends Number>` or `ArrayList<? super Number>` syntax. `extends` is generally used when you're going to consume (i.e. read) from the object in your method, `super` is used when you're going to produce (i.e. write). Given that printout is consuming, it's safe to use `extends`:

```
public void printNumbers(ArrayList<? extends Number> list) {
    list.forEach(System.out::println);
}

ArrayList<Integer> listInt = new ArrayList<Integer>();
printNumbers(listInt); // works
ArrayList<Double> listDbl = new ArrayList<Double>();
printNumbers(listDbl); // also works
```

There is a good answer in 
[Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java) for more in-depth explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not entirely correct. You cannot store a `Double` in an `ArrayList<? extends Number>`. Why not? Because an `ArrayList<? extends Number>` could be an `ArrayList<Integer>`. On the other hand, you can in fact store a `Double` in an `ArrayList<? super Number>`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. A simple collection that allows addition of both integers and doubles is in fact just `ArrayList<Number>`. `<? extends Number>` or `<? super Number>` is a fancy way to reference semi-unknown type, which would be known to be either in compile-time (in `extends`) or run-time (in `super`) — and they both don't really allow you to store *both* integers and doubles in the same collection as topic starter requests. I'll try to clarify answer now.

Comment: In a `List<? super Number>` you can in fact store both integers and doubles at the same time. In the same collection. For example: `List<? super Number> list = new ArrayList<Object>();`

Comment: The difference between `extends` and `super` has nothing to do with compile-time vs. runtime. All generic bounds are applied at compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

If you want them to hold any more than one type, use `Collection<Object>`.  However, you won't know what you're getting without doing some `if (x instanceof MyType)` calls, which are rather inefficient.

Comment: So a collection can contain two strings and two integers?

Comment: if you call it `Vector<Object>` (for instance) and store your `int` as `Integer`.

Comment: Yeah, sure, as long as these two share the same supertype, i.e. `Object`. Strictly speaking, you can't put `int` into collection, but you can put a `String` and `Integer` there.

Answer (score 2):

They have to be of the same Supertype. So if you have objects of type `A`, then a `Collection<A>` can store objects of type `A` and of every subtype of `A`.

If you want to allow arbitrary types, then use `Collection<Object>`, otherwise take the most general appropriate super-class.

However, you will then have to manually cast from the most general type (Object) to the specific type you have in mind. You can use the `typeof` operator to find out what the type is.

Answer (score 1):

Every Collection classes can contains heterogeneous objects **except TreeSet and TreeMap**. Since TreeSet and TreeMap  stores elements according to some sorting order. so, if objects are of different type it will not be able to sort it because comparison between the objects will not be possible for sorting.

Comment: `TreeMap` is not a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can but they should not (that's why generics have been put in place since 5th version of jdk) in general store different types, as this is the straight way to errors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes collections in java can hold more than one type as below. But it will throw an exception if done using the following way.

```
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    al.add(1);
    al.add("name");
    al.add(1.2f);

    Iterator itr =al.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(itr.next());
    }
```

Hence it's better to mention the type that you're using. To get rid of the exception the above program can be modified as below.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    al.add(1);
    al.add(2);
    al.add(3);

    Iterator itr =al.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(itr.next());
    }

    ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    al1.add("Words");
    al1.add("Names");
    al1.add("Characters");

    Iterator itr1 =al1.iterator();
    while(itr1.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(itr1.next());
    }
```

You can also use more than these types.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

My mistake the correct code is this one and

```
ArrayList<Elements>()=new ArrayList();
```

or

```
ArrayList<E>()=new ArrayList();
```

should be the correct declaration if you want to use Generics in Collection.

```
class Test
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // For Generic class of List
      ArrayList<E> arrL1 = new ArrayList<E>();
      arrL1.add("stackoverflow");
      arrL1.add(1);   
      Iterator itr1=list.iterator();

     while(itr1.hasNext())
     {
        System.out.println(itr1.next());
     }


  // for Particular datatype in List
    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>(); // Creating arraylist
    list.add("Ravi"); // Adding object in arraylist
    list.add("Vijay");
    list.add("Ravi");
    list.add("Ajay");

    // transversing the values
    Iterator itr=list.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(itr.next());
    }
}
```

}

> Output 1

```
stackoverflow

1
```

> Output 2

```
Ravi

Vijay

Ravi 

Ajay
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can also use `Collection<?>`.

Comment: You can, but you can't add anything to it.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can have more than one datatype in `ArrayList` of Collection.

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // For Generic class of List
        ArrayList<> arrL1 = new ArrayList<>();
        arrL1.add("stackoverflow");
        arrL1.add(1);

        // for Particular datatype in List
        ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>(); // Creating arraylist
        list.add("Ravi"); // Adding object in arraylist
        list.add("Vijay");
        list.add("Ravi");
        list.add("Ajay");

        // transversing the values
        Iterator itr=list.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output 1:**

> stackoverflow
>
> 1

**Output 2:**

> Ravi
>
> Vijay
>
> Ravi
>
> Ajay

Comment: That code does not compile for me because of the `ArrayList<>` syntax (*"illegal start of type"*). Also, I don't see where in the code the "Output 1" would come from.